# How to save entire http response to log file on server side just before responsing to the client

Tags: php, file

I am wondering if it is possible to save the entire http  response on the server side  at the end of some php script just before sending reponse? Even better if i can save response  in hex format?  Or  can i see it in apache log maybe?

many thanks

Edit:

```
      function shutDownFunction() {


        $error = error_get_last();

        if ( !empty($error) ) {

            header('HTTP/1.0  500' .$error );
        } else { 
           header('HTTP/1.0 200');
           return '<html> <body> ... </body></html>';
        }



    }

register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');

try { 

 $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

  //do some work here 

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        header('HTTP/1.0 503'); 

        die;
    }
```

And I want to save entire response inluding headers, i don-t know , for example  :

```
GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1
Host: net.tutsplus.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: [What problem are you trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)

Comment: I meant, why do you need to log this information?  What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
function callback($buffer)
{
  // Save the output (to append or create file)
  $fh = fopen("out.txt", "a");
  fwrite($fh, $buffer);
  fclose($fh);

  // Return the output
  return $buffer;
}

// Any thing that is indended to be sent to the client is stored in a buffer and callback is called
ob_start("callback");

// Write out to buffer here
echo "TEST";
echo " SOME MORE DATA";
echo "\r\nNEW LINE";
echo "<b>SOME HTML</b>";

// Send to client
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Not easy in just PHP alone, best in an apache log. Im sure there would be an option to log all outputs

Answer (score 2):

At te beggining of the script put:

```
ob_start();
```

and put this at the end of script

```
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;
file_put_contents(time().'output.txt', $output);
```